# Good bedding plants for Autumn/Fall colour UK

Tags: plant-recommendations, ornamental-plant

I'm getting my house ready to sell.  Because of building work there are a lot of bare patches of soil in the garden.  I'd like to put some colourful plants (ideally flowering) in to make it look attractive to buyers.

Can anyone recommend flowering plants that can be put in now (September) and give colour through until say the end of October in Oxfordshire on clay soil?  I've missed the boat for many of the usual recommendations (e.g. Autumn crocuses).  Something bright and easy like Petunias would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dwarf cyclamen - garden centres are usually full of them at this time of year, just make sure you buy those which are standing on display outdoors, not from the houseplant section inside. Otherwise, pansies, either the large flowered ones or the ones sold as 'viola' with smaller flowers. These should all flower right up to Christmas. You might also find Ornamental cabbage, these look good up to around end of November. Keep well watered during warm dry spells.